# P2V SBS Windows 2008: Mass Storage Driver issue around SCSI IDE changes - Boot BSOD Error 0x0000007b, 0xc0000034?

Tags: drivers, windows-sbs-2008, bsod, physical-to-virtual

Have done tons of reading on Spiceworks & outside on P2Vs, SBS, 2008, DC related threads and made lots of notes on all Pathways & Tools & Prep: (Please see Pg 1,2,3) so you know I've done the homework on all ways.

**Compiled Notes:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vtljsnk2yscybcr/P2V%20-%20SBS%20DC%20-%20Notes.docx?dl=0

- Currently prefer any Cold/ Offline Clone - As dont have another box, plus its safer/ better for DC to P2V offline.

---

**Regarding BSOD Error:**
From my Googling so far, It's due to Driver mismatch between Storage device on P hardware and V hardware.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/asksbs/2008/03/29/how-to-troubleshoot-the-stop-error-0x0000007b/

> 4. 0xc0000034 – This status code translates to STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND. This is the most common status code and is usually caused by a missing or corrupt driver.

[image]

**Physical:**

- Dell T410 +
- Dell LSI Logic Controller (Shows as: Dell SAS 6/iR Adapter Controller under Win 2012 R2).

PS: SBS originally boots off LSI RAID 0, and boots even when cloned to normal MoBo attached SATA disk, but the VHD clone of that SATA disk BSODs under HyperV.

**Virtual:**

- Hyper V 2012 R2 - Gen 1

Done several rounds of CHKDSK, Degfrag and even Defraggler + Freespace Defrag

**Likely Fixes/ Solutions - Researched so far?**

Figured we could add the REG fixes for AHCI, IDE, ATAPI into it, but does not seem to work.

Saw some posts about LSI / SCSI registry changes - But not sure if thats the way to go.

**Your Thoughts/ Suggestions?**

---

**Other methods tried:**

> 

- Also, the SBS Backup & Restore method in 2008, does not show any "Restore to different Hardware" Checkbox - Also, it wont allow me to Restore C-drive backup to a Expandable VHD with higher GB size.
- SCVMM Trial, MS MVMC, Disk2VHD, Paragon, Acronis, ShadowCraft - All pretty much failed to fix this with their so called Hardware Independent Recovery & conversion mechanisms.

PS: It is SBS Premium 2008 (not OEM) (before people assume/ question or jump)

Also, we cant move to 2012 R2 as yet  as bunch of Custom Apps are there on an App/ Data Server on Win 2008 and its all tightly linked.

(But down the line as the Custom apps are Chosen & replaced, 2012/16 or Zentayal may be on the cards)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> After having tried all variations and suggestions on changing drivers, registry keys and what not, I happened to come upon the only single hacky way that worked.
>
> Every converter failed as it did not manage to "resolve" the SCSI IDE Mass Storage issue that was causing the BSOD.
>
> The larger issue here is that the Physical machine has/ had Dell LSI SCSI hardware, and despite cloning the SBS 08 to an IDE drive as a Volume / Partition and enabling IDE/ ATAPI drivers etc. the OS seemed to "miss" its SCSI booting "sequence".

So these was successfully done in Stages:

**Stage 1**: P2V using VMWare Converter Standalone to VMWare VM with SCSI VMDK

This is a straight forward process using the Convert Physical machine Wizard. If need be we can add a relevant link for this.

**Stage 2**: Boot VM off SCSI VMDK with attached **Primary IDE VHD** (*Even an Empty VHD - Any tiny size: e.g. 1GB*).

This was easy to do in VMWare Workstation 10.0 and **this step seems to add certain IDE stuff to the SCSI booting which makes the OS IDE & SCSI boot capable/ able.**

We had tried the manual way of hacking registry keys many times to change the Mass Storage Driver and Boot drive issues, but it causes some issues.

I found this hacky & exceptional step on this forum discussion:
[How to convert VMWare image to Hyper-V images](http://chicagotech.net/netforums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15495)

> While most online discussions & suggestions only talk about converting VMDK to VHD, this one points out the **MassStorage booting issue (SCSI vs IDE) that causes the above BSOD all the time (as I've seen and read on the web) and plagues so many P2V + Hyper V attempts and SCSI to IDE change.**

**Stage 3**: On another Custom VMWare VM, attach above VMDK as **IDE for Primary booting.** Boot, let it complete and shutdown.

Now, the **drive & its OS have successfully booted via a Primary IDE** and are **primed for conversion to Hyper V (as Hyper V does not support booing from SCSI)**

**Stage 4**: Using Starwind V2V Converter (or another utility) convert the VMDK to VHD

**State 5**: On a new Hyper V VM attach output VHD as IDE drive and boot into OS

Comment: This! I've had an experience only with Starwind V2V converter. It just does its job. I've read that right now it has a new virtual hardware patch, and it the converting is much simpler now. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter

Comment: @Stuka - I did use the latest version of V2V but, and it probably does some patching after conversion to VHD, but its not perfect, so this LSI SCSI (physical) to IDE (Virtual) did not work directly. I had to go through the above steps. - Appreciate the ups./ points. This took me so many weeks of burning through crap to figure out. I did use V2V in one step as outlined above

Answer (score 0):

I sorted BSOB 7B on my SBS 2011 P2V.
(Original was on HP Server with Hardware RAID5 with failing hard disks.
New version on Hyper-V 2019)
by using this
http://www.manjeetjakhar.com/2013/09/how-to-fix-bsod-0x0000007b-on-win7-and.html

Spent 10 days looking for a solution

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.